# The most elegant solution to implement localisation in multi package project

Tags: ios, swift, module, localization, swift-package-manager

In our project we use many packages (Swift Package Manager) to split one big project for many atomic features and services.
Of-course each feature has own localisable resources, and also we want to allow to the end user of our packages to customise localisations and localise with different languages just in his project. At he same time we try to reach good looking non repeatable code. And this is example of our current solution:

```
internal extension String {

/// Copies could be localized by adding localizations files in project.
/// Also default localization could be changed by using the same keys in localization file in project
var localized: String {
    let localisationFromMainBundle = NSLocalizedString(self,
                                                       tableName: nil,
                                                       bundle: .main,
                                                       value: "",
                                                       comment: "")
    if localisationFromMainBundle == self {
        return NSLocalizedString(self,
                                 tableName: nil,
                                 bundle: .module,
                                 value: "",
                                 comment: "")
    } else {
        return localisationFromMainBundle
    }
}
```

}

You can see, that this code tries to localise text from .main bundle, but if it was not successful (localised string is equal to key) it tries to localise it from .module bundle.
And we use it in code just like

```
"localisation_key".localise
```

But we have one unpleasant moment here: we have to copy-past this code to each module, because   if we create one more utilities Package to keep this code, it starts to look for .module resources not inside of feature-specific module, where we call "key".localise, but inside of itself.

Does anybody knows how to implement it better?

Comment: What about using instead: `func localize(bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main)` (or by default the module one)i? That way it might be easier for upper level to decide which one to use? Default, or custom? Etc.

Comment: Probably I just can't understand, but we don't want to allow to choose bundle. We are inside Module and we use localisations from this module by code which is in the same module. And this works. Problem: I think that copy past the same extension to 5-100 modules is not right, and I tried to move presented extension to very base Module with public modifier, but in this case this extension starts to look localisations files in this very basic Module, but they are in one level above Module or few levels above (not in .main bundle, in .module but different)

Comment: You may try this: put this code into an extra package and ensure the code is inlined: `extension String {
  @inlinable
  @inline(__always)
  func localized() -> String { ... }
}`
Not sure if this works, let me know! ;)
I personally would go with something similar to what Larme suggested, though.

Comment: In my case making calculated property @inlinable does't help, because I got compiling error that Bundle.module is internal. Playing around use something else, does not help yet.

Comment: Now I decided to use Larme's idea